# CKAN DataPusher "cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections'"

Tags: python, flask, ckan

I want to run DataPusher with

```
sudo python3 datapusher/main.py deployment/datapusher_settings.py
```

I've been trying to change virtualenv with my own virtualenv, is still same, I do *'from collections import Mapping'* in **main.py** still same, and then I do same as main.py in my ****init**.py** still same, did I missed something?

the error message:

```
    /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py:102: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.26.16) or chardet (5.1.0)/charset_normalizer (2.0.12) doesn't match a supported version!
  warnings.warn("urllib3 ({}) or chardet ({})/charset_normalizer ({}) doesn't match a supported "
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rickotiaka/datapusher/datapusher/main.py", line 5, in <module>
    from datapusher import jobs
  File "/home/rickotiaka/datapusher/datapusher/jobs.py", line 20, in <module>
    import messytables
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/messytables/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from messytables.headers import headers_guess, headers_processor, headers_make_unique
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/messytables/headers.py", line 3, in <module>
    from messytables.core import Cell
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/messytables/core.py", line 2, in <module>
    from collections import Mapping
ImportError: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections' (/usr/lib/python3.10/collections/__init__.py)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that DataPusher does not yet support Python 3.10, which is the python version in Ubuntu 22.04.  If you try and install datapusher under 3.10, you get the "cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections'" error when you try and run it.

You can't fix this from within Python 3.10 (we have to wait for Datapusher to show python 3.10 compatibility on its github page).  But, you can still get things going by installing Python 3.8 alongside the default system-wide Python, then using Python 3.8 to make your virtualenv and install the datapusher portion.

This leaves the main CKAN instance running under Python 3.10 (this is correct and what is most tested for CKAN 2.10.1), while your datapusher only runs under Python 3.8.

Here are the commands I used to accomplish this on Ubuntu 22.04.  Other than changing the "python" commands to "python3.8" the instructions are the same:

1. Install Python 3.8 on your system.  I followed https://linuxgenie.net/how-to-install-python-3-8-on-ubuntu-22-04/:

```
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
    sudo apt install python3.8 python3.8-dev python3.8-venv
```

2. Test it works:   `python3.8 -V`  should show a verison
3. Now follow the regular datapusher install instructions but change "python" to "python3.8" in the commands:

```
    ### Create a python 3.8 virtualenv
    python3.8  -m venv /usr/lib/ckan/datapusher
    
    ### activate your new virtualenv
    cd /usr/lib/ckan/datapusher
    . bin/activate
    
    ### check it's python 3.8:
    python -V
    
    ### Create a source directory and switch to it
    mkdir /usr/lib/ckan/datapusher/src
    cd /usr/lib/ckan/datapusher/src
    
    ### Clone the source (you should target the latest tagged version)
    git clone -b 0.0.18 https://github.com/ckan/datapusher.git
    
    ### Install the DataPusher and its requirements
    cd datapusher
    sudo /usr/lib/ckan/datapusher/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt
    sudo /usr/lib/ckan/datapusher/bin/python setup.py develop
    
    ### Install uswgi (for production install)
    pip install uswgi
    cd deployment
```

Edit `datapusher-uwsgi.ini` to suit (change uid/gid if not running as root)

Don't forget to `chown -R USER:GROUP /usr/lib/ckan/datapusher` to the right user/group!

If you are going to use High Availability (Postgres DB) then change the database URL in datapusher_settings.py, and also:  `pip install psycopg2`

Finally, you should be able to run it with:   `/usr/lib/ckan/datapusher/bin/uwsgi -i /usr/lib/ckan/datapusher/src/datapusher/deployment/datapusher-uwsgi.ini`

and you should get a working datapusher without the error!  Now just add to supervisorctl and you're done!    The virtualenv will ensure the correct python version is there for datapusher only.